# beginner question about arrays in structs in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I would like to create a struct and use it inside an other struct as an array. My problem is that I don't know how big array I would like to allocate, I will only know once I am in a function. I mean I would like to use [] instead of a pre-determined constant, like 10000.

I think if you look at my code it would be self-explanatory. Can you help me how to make this code work? Moreover it would help me a lot if you could tell me what is the name of the topic I am asking about (is it dynamic arrays?) and that where can I find articles/tutorials about this topic.

Here is the code with my broken way of thinking about arrays in structs.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct keyframe {
    bool a;
    int b;
    int c;
};


struct keyframe_file {
    const int num_views;
    const int num_keyframes;
    keyframe keyframes[];
};


int main() {

    keyframe_file my_file;

    my_file.num_views = 1;
    my_file.num_keyframes = 6;

    my_file.keyframes = new keyframe[my_file.num_keyframes];

    my_file.keyframes[0].a = true;
    my_file.keyframes[0].b = 5;
    my_file.keyframes[0].c = 9;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I guess `how to create resizeable array` or `how to create a limitless array` are some good topic for your question.

Comment: "dynamic memory allocation" and "containers" are good search terms.

Comment: consider the answer that I gave even if you don't want to change the correct answer, it doesn't matter, what matters is that you can't assign values to constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it suits your purpose, an STL container (`std::vector`) is easily one of the best options - the less memory management you have to worry about, the better.

In any case, look at the struct definition Nawaz posted above - that's exactly how it should be. Dynamic arrays in C++ are simply pointers. You have, however, allocated the memory properly in your code, but you haven't freed it (so it's leaking). Since you allocated with `new []` you will need to

```
delete [] my_file.keyframes;
```

in order to free the memory properly.

Resizing is another issue: with a smart implementation, array resizing can be an amortized O(1) operation which is nice. When you resize, it will always take you O(n) since you need to copy all the elements into a new array of different size, but if you do it half as much, it becomes O(1). That is, double the array each time you need to resize. Here is a very quick example

```
void resize()
{
  if(numOfElementsInArray == sizeOfArray)
  {
    ArrayType * arr = new ArrayType[sizeOfArray*2]; // Allocate a double size array
    for(int i=0;i<sizeOfArray;++i)
      currentArray[i] = arr[i];
    delete [] currentArray; // Free memory in old array
    currentArray = arr; // Set the array to our new one
    sizeOfArray *= 2; // Double the size
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** The example above does not take into account space complexity; that said, if you have 5000 elements, and remove all but 5, this method with not shrink it (which is probably what you will want to do for all practical purposes)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I learned from it and I accepted yours to help with the points!

Comment: "Dynamic arrays in C++ are simply pointers" - dynamically-allocated arrays are arrays. Pointers to their first elements are simply pointers. If you do `Foo *x = new Foo[2];`, then `x` is not a dynamic-allocated array. It is a pointer to the first element of one.

Comment: @jdl: amortized O(1) is not inefficient nor is it CPU consuming/slow (it runs in constant time over the program's execution time - i.e. amortized). If my explanation didn't make sense, read more here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array#Geometric_expansion_and_amortized_cost

Answer (score 5):

Use a `std::vector`.

```
struct keyframe_file {
    const int num_views;
    const int num_keyframes;
    std::vector<keyframe> keyframes;
};

int main() {
    keyframe_file frame;
    frame.keyframes.resize(...);
}
```

Comment: Just note that serialization will be an issue.  If you're reading the struct in from a file or something (the struct being called "keyframe_file" implying this might be the case), you'll need some functionality to read in and reassemble the struct rather than reading it in directly.

Comment: @DeadMG: That is not enough. The struct needs a constructor, as the first two members are `const`, and hence they cannot be assigned. They must be initialized with values, which is possible using constructor only, as the struct is no more a POD.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am using it now and it works perfectly! The const doesn't need to be there its my choice and in this case there was no point using consts, so I deleted them!

Comment: @DeadMG: it's not a good idea for a beginner to use STL classes.

Comment: @Mr.: Au contraire! Beginners should use STL classes right from the beginning and struggle with pointers later on. At least according to Mr. Stroustrup ;-)

Comment: @FredOverflow: I have to keep silent when Mr. Stroustrup Speaks ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to be almost correct, except for two things:

1. `keyframes` needs to be a `keyframe*` rather than a `keyframe[]`
2. You forgot to `delete` the memory you allocated

Answer (score 0):

That is incomplete type. In C++, array must be provided with size, and the size must be known at compile time itself.

You're using `new`, with which you should be using *pointer*.

```
struct keyframe_file {
    const int num_views;
    const int num_keyframes;
    keyframe *keyframes;
};
```

But `std::vector<keyframe>` is still a better choice, as @DeadMG already suggested.

By the way, the first two members are `const` in the struct, that means, they *cannot* be **assigned** value, as you're doing in your code. They must be **initialized** with values  you want them to hold. That implies, now with `vector`, you've to include a constructor, to initialize the struct, as the struct is *no more* a POD.

```
struct keyframe_file {
    const int num_views; //const member
    const int num_keyframes; //const member
    std::vector<keyframe> keyframes;

    keyframe_file(int nviews, int nkeyframes) 
    : num_views(nviews), num_keyframes(nkeyframes), keyframes(nkeyframes){}
};


keyframe_file my_file(1,6); //done!
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, now I know more about consts. Luckily in the example above I decide what code to use, so I could simply afford not to use consts.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested "Vector" is they safest way to do it.
But if it is only about making your code work (without resizing and stuff) the following should be working:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct keyframe {
    bool a;
    int b;
    int c;
};


struct keyframe_file {
    const int num_views;
    const int num_keyframes;
    keyframe* keyframes;
};


int main()
{
    keyframe_file my_file = {1, 6};  // initialization needed bcause of 'const int'

    my_file.keyframes = new keyframe[my_file.num_keyframes];

    for (int i = 0; i < my_file.num_keyframes; i++)
    {
        my_file.keyframes[i].a = true;
        my_file.keyframes[i].b = 5 + i;
        my_file.keyframes[i].c = 9 - i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

somewhere in your code, when you are done using the array you have to call `delete [] my_file.keyframes;` as already mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

Use pointers and apply to your structure!

```
int *p;
p = new int;
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct keyframe {
    bool a;
    int b;
    int c;
};


struct keyframe_file {
    const int num_views;
    const int num_keyframes;
    keyframe *keyframes;
};


int main() {
    keyframe_file my_file;
    my_file.num_views = 1;
    my_file.num_keyframes = 6;

    for (int i = 0; i < my_file.num_keyframes; i++){
         my_file.keyframes = new keyframe; //<---
    }

    my_file.keyframes[0].a = true;
    my_file.keyframes[0].b = 5;
    my_file.keyframes[0].c = 9;

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a basic rule when using dynamic arrays in c++, especially when using it inside structs or classes, and it's to delete what you no longer need.

If you want to make your struct dynamic, it's easy, just replace the `[]` with `*` and the array will become dynamic, but it's not over yet, there is a lot of work.

You have to construct the array and destory it, and destoroying it is possible and useful noly with destructors, like this:

```
struct keyframe_file
{
    const int num_views;
    const int num_keyframes;
    keyframe* keyframes;

    ~keyframe_file() // this is the destructor
    {
        delete[] keyframes;
    }
};
```

Yet even that code isn't going to work at all, since you are assigning values to constants in variable `my_file` after creating it, it's illegal in c++, you should then use classes instead.

Using classes with dynamic arrays is very easy and interesting and makes your code very good, you don't have to know too much to do that, just learn what is a **constructor**, an **initializer**,  **destructor**, **private** and **public** and go on with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct keyframe
{
    bool a;
    int b,c;
};

class keyframe_file
{
public:
    keyframe_file(int NV, int NKF):num_keyframes(NKF),num_views(NV)
    {
        keyframes = new keyframe[num_keyframes];
    }
    ~keyframe_file()
    {
        delete[] keyframes;
    }
private:
    const int num_views;
    const int num_keyframes;
    keyframe* keyframes;
};

int main()
{
    keyframe_file my_file(1,6);
    return 0;
}
```

This code works very well, it allows you to assign value to the constants `num_views` and `num_keyframes` for one time when creating the object (variable) `my_file`.

Remember, you are a C++ programmer, be proud of that, and use classes instead of structs and dynamic arrays instead of static ones.

Hope that's useful.

Comment: I expect this code will throw warnings on some compilers, since the data members `num_views` and `num_keyframes` aren't initialized in the same order that they appear in the initializer list in the constructor. More importantly, `keyframe_file` is missing a copy ctor, which should either be defined to allocate its own array, or else made private (in C++0x marked `delete`) to prevent use. In this case no need to worry about the copy assignment operator, since there are `const` data members, but otherwise the same would apply to that. `vector` does all this for you.